# No results returned by the Query error in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, database, jsp, postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a data into a table. After executing the query i am getting an exception stating

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:284)
```

The data is getting inserted successfully, but i have no idea why i am getting this exception ??

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use

```
executeUpdate
```

instead of

```
executeQuery
```

if no data will be returned (i.e. a non-`SELECT` operation).

Comment: Beauty ! works perfectly.. but y is it like executeUpdate works but executeQuery doesnt work ?? in both casesdata is getting inserted properly.

Comment: @RageshKr, it gets inserted correctly, but the Java database connector is afterwards expecting data, and none comes. So the error happens after the insert.

Answer (score 37):

Please use **@Modifying** annotation over the **@Query** annotation.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE Users set coins_balance = coins_balance + :coinsToAddOrRemove where user_id = :user_id", nativeQuery = true)
    int updateCoinsBalance(@Param("user_id") Long userId, @Param("coinsToAddOrRemove") Integer coinsToAddOrRemove);
```

The same is true for any DML query (i.e. DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT)

Comment: Thanks for this, I wanted a solution for a JPQL query!

Answer (score 15):

Using @Modifying and @Transaction fixed me

Comment: Its @Transactional

Comment: @Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = Update/Delete/InstertQuery , nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 7):

The problem that brought me to this question was a bit different - I was getting this error when deleting rows using an interface-based Spring JPA Repository. The cause was that my method signature was supposed to return some results:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM table t WHERE t.some_id IN (:someIds)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> deleteBySomeIdIn(@Param("someIds") Collection<Long> someIds);
```

Changing the return type to `void` resolved the issue:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM table t WHERE t.some_id IN (:someIds)", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteBySomeIdIn(@Param("someIds") Collection<Long> someIds);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want last generated id, you can use this code after using executeUpdate() method

```
 int update = statement.executeUpdate()
 ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
 if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
  key = rs.getLong(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Problem using `addBatch` and `executeBatch` as following:

```
statement.addBatch("DELETE FROM public.session_event WHERE id = " + entry.getKey());
statement.executeBatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execute` instead of `executeQuery`
if no data will be returned

It can also be useful when executing a script with DDL statements (i.e. CREATE/ALTER/DROP).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).