# SQL update statement in eclipse will update database but will throws SQL exception

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to update a database from eclipse. The database will update, however, the java program will throw a SQLException after the  database is updated.

```
Statement stmnt = null;
    Connection connection = establishConnection();
    stmnt = connection.createStatement();
    stmnt.executeQuery("UPDATE table1  SET column2='"+description+"' WHERE column1='"+id+"'");
```

this is what is printed in the console:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query
```

Comment: check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276059/no-results-returned-by-the-query-error-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

[`executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) should be used for statements that return a `ResultSet`. For other statements, you should use [`executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-):

```
stmnt.executeUpdate
    ("UPDATE table1  SET column2='"+description+"' WHERE column1='"+id+"'");
```

Side note:
Using string manipulation this way may expose your code to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.