# DB migration giving PSQLexception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to setup an existing ruby project. However, during rake db:migrate, its giving the following error:

> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results
>   were returned by the query.: INSERT INTO "schema_migrations"
>   ("version") VALUES ('20170426211531')

Comment: Have you created db? If not, use `rake db:create` and then migrate it.

Comment: I have created the db. Problem is with migrations only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21276130/5315974

Comment: @VaoTsun mine is ruby project. can't update gem