# Springboot File upload happen and Data save in the Database but give 500 error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a class that has Users @entity. Which has a profile picture that needs to update, When I pass the @Query the image name update and I can see the image in the folder too. But in my API, I have a imageName return so I can do assynchronize change. The weired part is when I upload the image, image get uploaded in a folder and in the database too, but throw 500 error. Never saw this happen Before. Any help will be appreciated.

POJO Class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {

  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "firstname")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "lastname")
  private String lastName;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "email")
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "role")
  private String role;

  @Column(name = "profile_picture")
  private String profilePicture;
}
```

Profile Picture Class

```java
public class ProfilePicture {
  private MultipartFile profileImage;
  private String profileImageName;
}
```

Repository

```java
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String> {
  @Query(value = "UPDATE users SET profile_picture = :saveImage WHERE username = :username", nativeQuery = true)
  public String updateUserProfilePictureForUsername(@Param("saveImage") String saveImage, @Param("username") String username);
}
```

Service:

```java
public void saveProfileImage(ProfilePicture saveImage, String username) {
  String imageName = saveImage.getProfileImageName();
  profileRepo.updateUserProfilePictureForUsername(imageName, username);
}
```

REST API

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/uploadprofileimage")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String uploadProfilePicture(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile Imagefile, @RequestParam("username") String username) throws IOException {

  String profileImageName = Imagefile.getOriginalFilename();
  ProfilePicture profileImage = new ProfilePicture();

  String fileFolderPath = "/Users/Desktop/Documents/" + username + /ProfilePictures/";
  File filePath = new File(fileFolderPath);
  if (!filePath.exists()) {
    filePath.mkdirs();
  }

  File file = new File(fileFolderPath, profileImageName);
  profileImage.setProfileImageName(profileImageName);
  profileImage.setProfileImage(Imagefile);
  profileImage.getProfileImage().transferTo(file);
  profileService.saveProfileImage(profileImage, username);
  return profileImage.getProfileImageName();
}
```

This is the Solution using Lambda Expression.

```java
public Users saveProfileImage(ProfilePicture saveImage, String username) {
  String imageName = saveImage.getProfileImageName();

  return profileRepo.findById(username).map( user -> { 
    user.setProfilePicture(imageName);
    return profileRepo.save(user);
  }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Something went wrong "));
}
```

Comment: maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276059/no-results-returned-by-the-query-error-in-postgresql

Comment: Not really But I figured out using Lambda. Answer posted above.