# Passing variable to Postgresql from Spark with scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, hive

Usually I can access Hive table from Spark by using the following:

```
val start = "20191009"
val end   = "20200112"
val df= ss.sql(s"""select * from myTable where dat between '$start' and '$end' """)
```

By previous code I can pass variable to the **SQL** by including `$` in front of the variable.

Now I want to do same previous logic but with the `postgres` table. 
I have Postgres table that I connected to it through:

```
val statement = connection.createStatement()

var gg = statement.executeQuery("update myTable set firstV='NewValue' where SecondV =$val;")
```

I want to pass a variable to the previous sql ( to val variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code snippet is not using the `s` modifier, hence `$` substitution will not work. Try

````
var gg = statement.executeQuery(s"update myTable set firstV='NewValue' where SecondV =$val;")```
````

Answer (score 0):

As `@Charlie Flowers` hit part of the issue; I missed the `s` modifier in front of the query. The other issue was trying to save the result of the Postgres table in a variable (in my case `gg`), the query will be directly executed on Postgres database/table, so I just removed the `var gg =` part.

```
statement.executeQuery(s"update myTable set firstV='NewValue' where SecondV =$val;")
```

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276059/no-results-returned-by-the-query-error-in-postgresql) helped me alot, since I used `executeQuery` while I have to use `executeUpdate`, so my query should be:

```
statement.executeUpdate(s"update myTable set firstV='NewValue' where SecondV =$val;")
```